# What section in the Federal Aviation Regulations deals with fueling commercial aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, fuel, refueling

What section of the FAR deals with fueling commercial aircraft?
I can't seem to find the section. Is is under ground handling?
The actual process and safety, not the airworthiness of the fuel systems.

Thanks

Comment: Why would this be in the FARs?  It would most likely be in the AFM for the aircraft under an addendum called `Fuel Servicing` perhaps.

Comment: "The actual process and safety" is still pretty broad and vague. Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to know? Whatever it is, as @wbeard52 stated, it's most likely not covered in 14 CFR ("FARs") (or the CFR at all).

Comment: TypeIA yeah. specifically looking for if passengers and the APU can be running during refueling on a commercial airplane. I am an AME (A&P mechanic) and always our practises are passengers off the plane. But I cannot find any references. only refernce I can find is an AC 00-34A not to energize plane circuits during refueling. besides the necessay ones for refueling

Comment: It may help you review the regulatory information **linked** in my answer below (FAR 139.1).

Answer (score 3):

**Your Question:** *What section of the FAR deals with fueling commercial aircraft?*

**Answer:**
With some exceptions, as specified in [14 CFR Part 139.1](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-G/part-139/subpart-A/section-139.1), airports used in the U.S. (including territories or possession of the United States) for most commercial/air carrier type operations must be certificated by the FAA under 14 CFR Part 139. FAR Part 139 **contains regulatory sections relating to the** **fueling of aircraft**.

A pertinent example is [FAR Part 139.321 (b)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-G/part-139/subpart-D/section-139.321#p-139.321(b)), which states:

**Section 139.321 Handling and storing of hazardous substances and materials.**

> (b) Each certificate holder must establish and maintain standards authorized by the Administrator for protecting against fire and explosions in storing, dispensing, and otherwise handling fuel (other than articles and materials that are, or are intended to be, aircraft cargo) on the airport. These standards must cover facilities, procedures, and personnel training and must address at least the following:
>
> > (1) Bonding.
> >
> > (2) Public protection.
> >
> > (3) Control of access to storage areas.
> >
> > (4) Fire safety in fuel farm and storage areas.
> >
> > (5) Fire safety in mobile fuelers, fueling pits, and fueling cabinets.
> >
> > (6) Training of fueling personnel in fire safety in accordance with paragraph (e) of this section. Such training at Class III airports must be completed within 12 consecutive calendar months after June 9, 2004.
> >
> > (7) The fire code of the public body having jurisdiction over the airport.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question re: fueling.

Comment: @JuanJimenez The AC you reference in your answer states on its first page, - para 3, Applicability item #2, the following verbiage: "This AC provides one, but not the only, acceptable means of meeting the requirements of 14 CFR, Part 139, Certification of Airports." Also, the title of the AC uses virtually identical language contained in FAR 139.321. The contents of the AC you reference demonstrates it provides one method of meeting the requirements of Part 139. Part 139 is a regulation that deals with, among other things, the fueling of aircraft. So, I disagree with your comment.

Comment: The FAR in question does not provide a single line of guidance on methodology, it only requires the airport to develop standards as part of airport certification, and the general areas the standards must address. It leaves everything else to the imagination. That is where the AC comes in, providing non-binding guidance as to methodology. "This AC contains specifications and guidance for the storage, handling, and dispensing of aviation fuel on airports. It also provides standards and guidance for the training of personnel who conduct these activities." So, my opinion stands.

Comment: What would make sense, though, is to combine your answer and mine into a FAR reference that is generalized, and an AC that is more specific, but still leaves the nitty-gritty to the airport operator.

Answer (score 0):

FAR's don't address that, the only FAR that even speaks to that just says the airport must have standards. No details. For what you are asking, there is an advisory circular on the subject, [AC 150/5230-4C](https://www.faa.gov/airports/resources/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentnumber/150_5230-4), which provides guidance on methodology.